# Draw curve like "InterpCrv" (Curve: Interpolate Points) in Rhinoceros 4.0

Tags: c#, draw, curve, interpolation

Could you please help me with drawing curves.

Curve in Rhinoceros 4.0:

http://habrastorage.org/storage2/6be/922/279/6be9222791436832a5374264ac877606.png

When I use DrawCurve in C#, I have ugly curve :(

http://habrastorage.org/storage2/84f/e58/c2c/84fe58c2cbef9a0e10e7be8cd7dd04a9.png

How can I make my curve more beautifull like in rhino?

Comment: Links are broken now.

Answer (score 1):

DrawCurve has a parameter "tension". You can adjust it as needed to soften your curve.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/554h284b.aspx

Comment: if I use 0.9 tension. I recieved more ugly curve http://habrastorage.org/storage2/400/5d6/126/4005d6126ad02565fa14805b51985cec.png

Comment: Can you post your call to DrawCurve?